# PASAR RESULTADOS DE CONSULTA A COLUMNAS

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle

Buen día,

tengo la siguiente consulta

```
select e.documento,e.NOMBRE1||' '||TRIM(e.NOMBRE2)||' '||e.APELLIDO1||' '||e.APELLIDO2 "NOMBRE",l.concepto,l.valor


FROM empleado e,vinculacion v,detallevinculacion vd,liquidacion l


WHERE e.CODEMPLEADO = '555222' AND e.CODEMPLEADO = v.CODEMPLEADO AND v.NUMVINCULACION = vd.NUMVINCULACION AND  vd.TIPOREG = 2 AND v.CODVINCULACIONESTADO = 1 AND vd.NUMVINCULACION = l.NUMVINCULACION AND l.CODNOMINA = '01/30/2017'
```

el resultado es:

```
NUMDOCUMENTO ;NOMBRE ;CODCONCEPTO ;VALOR
555222 ;PEDRO PEREZ;SUBASICO ;1491589
555222 ;PEDRO PEREZ;PRORT ;1
555222 ;PEDRO PEREZ;DIASS ;30
555222 ;PEDRO PEREZ;DIASR ;30
555222 ;PEDRO PEREZ;DIASL ;30
555222 ;PEDRO PEREZ;DIDOT ;30
555222 ;PEDRO PEREZ;IBINC ;1491589
555222 ;PEDRO PEREZ;PROBS ;62150
333666 ;JUAN PARDO;SUBASICO ;1491589
333666 ;JUAN PARDO;PRORT ;1
333666 ;JUAN PARDO;DIASS ;30
333666 ;JUAN PARDO;DIASR ;30
333666 ;JUAN PARDO;DIASL ;30
333666 ;JUAN PARDO;DIDOT ;30
333666 ;JUAN PARDO;IBINC ;1491589
333666 ;JUAN PARDO;PROBS ;62150
```

lo que necesito es mostrar los resultados de concepto como columnas y abajo el valor, es decir así:

```
NUMDOCUMENTO ;NOMBRE ;SUBASICO PRORT; DIASS; DIASR
555222 ;PEDRO PEREZ ;1491589 ;30 ;30 ;30
333666 ;JUAN PARDO ;1491589 ;30 ;30 ;30
```

es sobre una liquidación y los conceptos de liquidación son muchos digamos 100, y se hará sobre todos los empleados es decir que cuando quite la condición e.CODEMPLEADO = '555222' saldrá sobre todos los empleados.

vi algunos ejemplos con PIVOT pero para un numero de columnas fijas.

muchas gracias por su atención.

Comment: Algo complicado en una consulta, quizás te sea de ayuda usar un agrupador por numero de documento, pero deberás conocer los conceptos y seria una consulta horrible algo así: `SELECT NUMDOCUMENTO, NOMBRE, SUM(CASE WHEN CODCONCEPTO='SUBASICO' THEN VALOR ELSE 0 END) AS SUBASICO, ... FROM ... GROUP BY NUMDOCUMENTO`. Aunque insisto que seria una consulta horrible aun si lo simplificas con una función.

Comment: dudaa, para que sumar el básico?ningún valor debe sumarse lo que necesito es que cada concepto lleve su valor, ningún concepto se repite...

Comment: Es solo un ejemplo de como individualizar cada campo de texto en la fila, no lo tomes literal. Solo adaptalo a tu necesidad puntual. Aunque a decir verdad no he terminado por comprenderte.

Comment: @NederAlfonsoFandiñoAndrade he editado los resultados, lo que debe salir en la consulta es que cada empleado salga con sus conceptos y valores de manera horizontal